# Don't recognize text as keyword if it's surrounded by double quotes

Tags: color, listings

I'm trying to define language formatting for C#, but I'm having a problem. While it works fine for the most part, I don't want text that is in quotes to be characterized as keywords. Here's my language definition so far:

```
\definecolor{commentcolor}{RGB}{87,166,74}
\lstdefinelanguage{CSharp} {keywords=[1]{abstract, event, new, struct,
                as, explicit, null, switch,
                base, extern, object, this,
                bool, false, operator, throw,
                break, finally, out, true,
                byte, fixed, override, try,
                case, float, params, typeof,
                catch, for, private, uint,
                char, foreach, protected, ulong,
                checked, goto, public, unchecked,
                class, if, readonly, unsafe,
                const, implicit, ref, ushort,
                continue, in, return, using,
                decimal, int, sbyte, virtual,
                default, interface, sealed, volatile,
                delegate, internal, short, void,
                do, is, sizeof, while,
                double, lock, stackalloc,
                else, long, static,
                enum, namespace, string},

                keywordstyle=[1]\color{blue},
                commentstyle=\color{commentcolor},
                morecomment=[l]{//}, morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
                showstringspaces=false, showspaces=false,
                showtabs=true, extendedchars=true
                }
```

Here's some test input: `Console.WriteLine("Please  enter  in  a  string.");`

In this case, I don't want "in" and "string" to be highlighted blue.

Comment: Try this: `moredelim=[s]{("}{")}`

Comment: Thanks. How can I make this work with angle brackets? It doesn't seem to work well with interpolated strings.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your previous comment. The `moredelim=[s]{("}{")}` option (in `\lstdefinelanguage`) solves your problem.

Comment: Here's what I mean:

normally, it works fine. Take Console.WriteLine("Please enter in a string.") ;. That is correctly formatted with all-black text.

If we use it with interpolated strings, which include curly braces (sorry, I misspoke when I said "angle brackets"), such as: 
Console.WriteLine($"Your number plus five is: {numberPlusFive }!") ;
 the word "is" is still highlighted in blue.

Comment: Okay. Then try it: `moredelim=[l]{"}`

Comment: Thanks, that worked!